# aem Touch UI - page properties dialog add js/listner

Tags: javascript, adobe, aem

I am trying to add clientlibs folder(primary type as cq:ClientLibraryFolder and categories as cq.authoring.dialog). [As shown the link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51u21.png)

listner.js file is not loading. Is there different way for implementing clientlibs for page properties in AEM Touch UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load custom client libraries in page properties you have to add the attribute `extraClientlibs` to the page property dialog definition.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root 
    xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" 
    xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
    xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" 
    xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
    extraClientlibs="[your clientlib category]">

    [... dialog fields ...]
</jcr:root>
```

`extraClientlibs` is an array of the categories you want to load.

Example:

`extraClientlibs="[mycompany.clientlib.user,mycompany.clientlib.dialogs]"`

Comment: Okay so I've created a clientlib under the component and added the category 'x' to it. Created a cq:dialog and added the property extraClientlibs and set it to 'x'. Do I miss something?